# Allow remote access to mysql database on ubuntu server

Tags: mysql, database, ubuntu, server, remote-access

I have my database on one ubuntu server and i want to use the same database on that server as well as on other ubuntu server.I have tried all the possible tutorials available for allow remote access but it's not working.
I am getting the error below when i try to access the database from local machine

> A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond.

I have set bind-address=0.0.0.0 in my.cnf file and also create new user by following commands:

```
mysql –u root -p
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO root@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Is there any solution which can solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

make sure firewall isn't blocking your request.
disable firewall first sudo systemctl stop firewalld 
try connecting if it works then add mysql to firewall

## first start firewall again

sudo systemctl start firewalld

## lookup for your zone

sudo firewall-cmd --get-active-zone

## let's say it answer "work"

sudo firewall-cmd --permanent --zone=work --add-service=mysql

at last try connecting again